# Пересылка сообщений из чатов Telegram с анализом ключевых слов (вхождений) в текст

Tags: парсер, telegram

ребята. Стоит задача собрать софт, который будет по заданным каналам и чатам телеграм анализировать новые посты, искать в них вхождение ключевых слов (задается пользователем в софте) и в случае вхождения слова в текст сообщения чата или нового поста канала пересылать его на определенный канал. Функцию пересылки сообщений для каналов я реализовал, а вот как сделать то же самое для чатов ума не приложу. Ну и анализ вхождения ключевых слов в текст сообщения тоже. Буду очень признателен за помощь)

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events
import asyncio

api_id = мой id
api_hash = 'мой hash'

my_channel_id = -1002079987754
channels = [-1002137033499, -5831143277]

client = TelegramClient('acc', api_id, api_hash)
print("FREEDOM - Started")


@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=channels))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    await client.send_message(my_channel_id, event.message)
    print('new post')
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

with client:
    client.run_until_disconnected()
```